# Scanner function in while loop's statement causes runtime error

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Through using the debugger I've managed to find the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

import java.util.*;

```
public class CreateString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder solution = new StringBuilder();
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            Scanner inner_scanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
            String str = inner_scanner.next();
            while(inner_scanner.hasNextInt()) solution.append(str.charAt(inner_scanner.nextInt()));
            inner_scanner.close();
        }
        System.out.format("%d\n %s",solution.length(),solution);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

This is the while loop that I'm talking about. The basic premise of this code is that I get an input with first a string, and after that, a couple of numbers. Like this:

```
some_string 0 5 1 4
```

In the output I write out the characters that are in the indexes that these numbers index to. So I get:

```
s_oe
```

The problem is that when it finishes one cycle, it gets stuck and waits for the next input.

Comment: Maybe you should provide us the stacktrace? We could then help you.

Comment: I don't have that set up but I'll edit the question so the whole code is in it

Comment: You should close the inner scanner after you finish using it. That's also why try-with-resources is much better.

Comment: That may be the problem. Edit: Was not the problem but thanks

Comment: Is it mandatory to have all these loops ? Because I have 2 simple solutions.

Comment: No, but I could only think of doing it this way quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only one `Scanner`:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        var solution = new StringBuilder();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            var str = scanner.next();
            while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                solution.append(str.charAt(scanner.nextInt()));
            }
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.format("%d\n %s\n",solution.length(),solution);
    }
```

<sup>tried to not change the main structure (too much)</sup>

but using `hasNextInt()` will avoid the inner loop finishing until next token is present - so if you need one output for each input line, another approach is needed.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            var solution = new StringBuilder();
            var str = scanner.next();
            var inner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
            while (inner.hasNextInt()) {
                solution.append(str.charAt(inner.nextInt()));
            }
            inner.close(); 
            System.out.format("%d\n %s\n",solution.length(),solution);
        }
    }
```

or, better, using `try-with resource`, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66536830/scanner-function-in-while-loops-statement-causes-runtime-error/66538405#comment117624491_66536830) by Alex:

```
        var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            var solution = new StringBuilder();
            var str = scanner.next();
            try (var inner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine())) {
                while (inner.hasNextInt()) {
                    solution.append(str.charAt(inner.nextInt()));
                }
            }
            System.out.format("%d\n %s\n",solution.length(),solution);
        }
```

<sub>On Windows you need to type `Ctrl`-`Z` followed by `Return` on an own line to end standard input (if I am not wrong)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the loops and scanners you use are not mandatory, if I were you I would have done as following:

---

**Solution 1: (NOT TESTED)**

- Scanner.nextXXX() read a whole line. So `some_string 0 5 1 4` will be read in only one `.nextLine()`. For that:

  - I read in `String str`,
  - then split it in `params`. Where the string `word` will be at cell 0, then following cells will keep the indexes in params.
  - I parse each index in int, then pick the corresponding char in the string `word`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder solution = new StringBuilder();
        String str = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] params = str.split(" ");
        String word = params[0];
        String output = "";
        for(int i=1; i < params.length; i++) {
            int index = Integer.parseInt(params[i]);
            output += word.substring(index, index+1);
        }
}
```

---

**Solution 2: (NOT TESTED)**

- Here I wait the params as arguments of the application. So they will pass by the arguments of the main method (String args). Have a look at this [page](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/170/Syllabus/09/command-args.html)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
                
        String word = args[0];
        String output = "";
        for(int i=1; i < params.length; i++) {
            int index = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            output += word.substring(index, index+1);
        }
        System.out.println(output);
}
```

To test the solution 2:

```sh
javac Application.java
java Application some_string 0 5 1 4
```

---

**Solution 3 (TESTED)**

Now I understand your problem.

This behaves exactly as you explain. But to stop you must enter "exit".

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String inputStr = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] params = inputStr.split(" ");
            String word = params[0];
            boolean stop = word.equals("exit"); // check if we need to stop
            
            while( ! stop ) {
                String output = "";
                for (int i = 1; i < params.length; i++) {
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(params[i]);
                    if(word.length() >= (index+1))
                        output += word.charAt(index); 
                }
                System.out.println(output); // print result

                // read params for next step
                inputStr = scanner.nextLine();
                params = inputStr.split(" ");
                word = params[0];
                stop = word.equals("exit"); // check if we need to stop
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Exit !");
}
```

Comment: I see, I overcomplicated it. I will try it with the first method!

Comment: I still need multiple parameters. and the problem is with this `while (scanner.hasNextLine())`. It still waits for the next line that will never arrive. I don't know how else to write this one.

Comment: I tested it on another computer and it works there. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried to clean all the compiled .class ? Sometimes compilation is the cause of weird behaviours.

Comment: And what do you mean by "your solution still need multiple parameters" ? Because those I suggest works with many parameters, but you need to enter them only one time. Not interactively.

Comment: I need to input many sets of parameters one after the other. The problem is with `scanner.hasNextLine`

Comment: Now see if the 3rd solution is right for you.

Answer (score 0):

scanner.hasNext() will continue to wait for input until it reaches an EOF character. I think your only options are to either hardcode a special character that will break the loop or do something along these lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder solution = new StringBuilder();
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        String string = scanner.next();
        String[] indexes = scanner.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
        for (String index : indexes) {
            int parsedIndex = Integer.parseInt(index);
            if (parsedIndex >= 0 && parsedIndex < string.length()) {
                solution.append(string.charAt(parsedIndex));
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%d\n%s", solution.length(), solution);
    }
}
```